# import Angular Firebase into a project

Tags: angular, firebase

I'm trying to import Angular firebase into a project
`import * as firebase from "firebase"`
falls into error
`Cannot find module 'firebase' or its corresponding type declarations .ts(2307)`
and I ran the command to install @angular/firebase:
`npm I firebase @angular/fire --save`

what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

you can write import * as firebase from 'firebase/compat';
adn this work good

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/building-a-web-app-with-angular-and-firebase?hl=it#10) after the configuration on Firebase Cloud you need:

```
ng add @angular/fire
```

In your app module:

```
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, TaskDialogComponent, TaskComponent],
  imports: [
    ...
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

In your component:

```
...
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';


@Component({...})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog, private store: AngularFirestore) {}

  todo = this.store.collection('todo').valueChanges({ idField: 'id' }) as Observable<Task[]>;
  inProgress = this.store.collection('inProgress').valueChanges({ idField: 'id' }) as Observable<Task[]>;
  done = this.store.collection('done').valueChanges({ idField: 'id' }) as Observable<Task[]>;
  ...
}
```